# How much does Signal Jamming increase scanning times by?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

I have a mission to counter the Dark Event signal jamming, which increases scanning times for all six weeks. It certainly seems pretty bad, but it doesn't say how much scanning times are increased by, and I'm having trouble finding an answer either online or by digging through the config files.

I wouldn't be too concerned about this and would just try to counter it, but unfortunately the mission it got assigned too has a ranking of "DIFFICULT" and the "Low Profile" modification which only allows me to bring low ranking soldiers along. So before I decide to gamble on sending a squad of squaddies along to probably get themselves killed, I'd like some idea just how much of a threat this Dark Event is.

[image]

How much does Signal Jamming increase scan times for?

Comment: So  this did wind up going off, and it is a pretty notable increase (all scan times were around ~12 days), but I'm still not sure how much it increases it by. I did see one 13 time, so it must do something other than just doubling it. I'm going to take another deeper look through the config files when I have time to see if I can find anything more concrete, provided someone doesn't come along with an answer before then.

Comment: My feeling was that it is either +50% or +100%. I think that even though you saw a scan time of 13 days, it is likely to be doubling. I would not be surprised if the game uses decimal scan times and simply truncates them. We know it rounds the displayed percentage in the shot hit chances.

Answer (score 1):

From comments, the effect seems to be a doubling.

> So this did wind up going off, and it is a pretty notable increase (all scan times were around ~12 days), but I'm still not sure how much it increases it by. I did see one 13 time, so it must do something other than just doubling it. I'm going to take another deeper look through the config files when I have time to see if I can find anything more concrete, provided someone doesn't come along with an answer before then. – 
> Wipqozn - Oct 16, 2018 at 23:37

> My feeling was that it is either +50% or +100%. I think that even though you saw a scan time of 13 days, it is likely to be doubling. I would not be surprised if the game uses decimal scan times and simply truncates them. We know it rounds the displayed percentage in the shot hit chances. – 
> Roijan says reinstate Monica - Oct 19, 2018 at 21:31